# List of all possible classes of R objects

Tags: r

Assuming a fresh R installation, a clean `.Rprofile`, no additional packages loaded, and no previous calls of the kind `class(x) <- "new.class"`: What are the possible return values of `class(x)`?

Comment: I'm not sure how comprehensive [this is](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/BasicClasses.html), but it should help.

Comment: Thanks. These are the basic classes. But what about "lm" etc?

Comment: Right, that's a good point. I'll see what else I can find.

Comment: There are probably too many to name. What are you actually trying to get at? Are you looking for a list of classes that have specialized implementations for generic functions?

Comment: Only out of interest, no special application in mind. What are the possible return values of class(x)?

Comment: At least with S3 objects, there's no formal class registration. A "class" is just a character attribute on any object. In theory, `class()` can return any character value. Different versions of R may choose to return different/new classes.

Comment: You could go through the sources to find which class values are set. Might be a bit tricky if that happens in C code.

Comment: That's what i was thinking @Roland. You'd have to parse the base C code in addition to all R code in the base functions. And there's not just one way to assign a class so you'd have to be pretty flexible with what you search for. It doesn't sound feasible.

Comment: There are probably a few issues with this, but searching for `as.xyz` might be a start: `bpDf <- subset(data.frame(
    na.omit(installed.packages()[,c("Package","Priority")])),
  Priority=="base"); 
sapply(bpDf[,1], function(x){
  funs <- unclass(
    lsf.str(envir=asNamespace(x),all=T,
      pattern="^as\\..*"))
  if(length(funs)>0){
    data.frame(Function=funs,Package=x)
  }
})`

Comment: In addition to cataloging the `as.` methods, you might want to look at the classes that have an available `print` method. `methods(print)`

Comment: One could also parse the Rd files for their `value` field, which typically names the class of the object returned by a function.

Answer (score 4):

## Possible values of `class` in R

The question is: **What are the possible values class can take in R?** In R, users can define their own classes (as many as you want). Try creating a class for object x using `class(x) <- "new.class"`. 
But, at a clean install, R starts with this [**list of basic classes**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/BasicClasses.html).

Inspect the class of an object using `class()`.

**Atomic classes**

Classes help describe the type of data contained in a vector. Coercion (changing classes) moving *up* the subsequent list is safe—it will preserve information. But changing class *downward* may lose information.

- character `c("hello", "world")`
- complex   `c(as.complex(-1), 2i)`
- numeric   `c(as.integer(10), 3L)`
- integer   `c(100, .5)`
- logical   `c(TRUE, FALSE)`

**Other common classes**

Classes also help describe the logical structure of the data. (Note: `type` is the physical structure of the data, and sometimes the `class` is the same as the `type` thanks to *inheritance*.)

- atomic vectors: `class(my.atomic.vector)` will return one of the value from the list above, all elements are homogenous
- matrix: a vector with special 2-dimension attributes
- array: a vector with special n-dimension attributes
- list: elements can be from heterogeneous classes
- data frame: a list with special properties

Comment: great help here

Answer (score 1):

**Find defined classes in R**

I had the same question and to me a the best way to find out the defined classes was to simply type in `is.` and see what appears in the autocompletion menu. Like this:

[image: is.]

As you can see you get a list which even considers the loaded packages. Here I have `ggplot2` loaded and the corresponding classes are shown in the menu, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to fetch all calls to `class(*) <- *` in base R code and print first all the strings that make up classes, then all the calls that define classes, the former is cleaner but loses info on which strings go together to form classes > 1.

```r
all_class_definitions <- list()
rec <- function(x) {
  if(!is.call(x)) return(invisible(NULL))
  if(identical(x[[1]], quote(`<-`)) && is.call(x[[2]]) && identical(x[[c(2, 1)]], quote(class))) {
    # if the rhs is a symbol or a call to `class()` or `oldClass()` it's not interesting to us
    rhs <- x[[3]]
    if (is.symbol(rhs)) return(NULL)
    if (is.call(rhs) && list(rhs[[1]]) %in% expression(class, oldClass)) return(NULL)
    all_class_definitions[[length(all_class_definitions) + 1]] <<- rhs
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  invisible(lapply(x, rec))
}

pkgs <- c("stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", "methods", "base")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
  ns <- asNamespace(pkg)
  funs <- Filter(is.function, as.list(ns))
  for (fun in funs) {
    rec(body(fun))
  }
}

# we get a fairly long list (185 for me on mac and R version 4.1.3)
# of more or less clean classes

# We can clean it up further and extract strings, we'll lose info on classes 
# of length > 1 but have a neater result
all_class_scalars <- character()
rec2 <- function(call) {
  if(is.character(call)) all_class_scalars[[length(all_class_scalars) + 1]] <<- call
  if(!is.call(call) && !is.list(call)) return(invisible(NULL))
  invisible(lapply(call, rec2))
}
rec2(all_class_definitions)
```

```r
sort(unique(all_class_scalars))
#>   [1] "anova"                  "aov"                    "aovproj"               
#>   [4] "aovprojlist"            "ar"                     "arima0"                
#>   [7] "AsIs"                   "aspell"                 "aspell_inspect_context"
#>  [10] "bibentry"               "Bibtex"                 "browseVignettes"       
#>  [13] "CairoSymbolFont"        "CIDFont"                "citationFooter"        
#>  [16] "citationHeader"         "class"                  "colorConverter"        
#>  [19] "data.frame"             "Date"                   "dendrogram"            
#>  [22] "dist"                   "DLLRegisteredRoutines"  "dump.frames"           
#>  [25] "ecdf"                   "factanal"               "factor"                
#>  [28] "formula"                "ftable"                 "hclust"                
#>  [31] "hsearch"                "hsearch_db"             "htest"                 
#>  [34] "infl"                   "integrate"              "Latex"                 
#>  [37] "libraryIQR"             "list.of"                "listof"                
#>  [40] "lm"                     "loadings"               "logLik"                
#>  [43] "manova"                 "maov"                   "medpolish"             
#>  [46] "mlm"                    "mtable"                 "mts"                   
#>  [49] "multicomp"              "NativeRoutineMap"       "nls"                   
#>  [52] "nlsModel"               "nlsModel.plinear"       "noquote"               
#>  [55] "numeric_version"        "ordered"                "packageDescription"    
#>  [58] "packageInfo"            "packageIQR"             "packageStatus"         
#>  [61] "Pair"                   "pairwise.htest"         "Pattern"               
#>  [64] "person"                 "prcomp"                 "princomp"              
#>  [67] "profile"                "profile.nls"            "profiler"              
#>  [70] "profiler.nls"           "qr"                     "raster"                
#>  [73] "recordedplot"           "relistable"             "RGBcolorConverter"     
#>  [76] "sessionInfo"            "socket"                 "sortedXyData"          
#>  [79] "spec"                   "srcfile"                "srcfilealias"          
#>  [82] "srcfilecopy"            "stepfun"                "stl"                   
#>  [85] "StructTS"               "summary.aov"            "summary.aovlist"       
#>  [88] "summary.glm"            "summary.lm"             "summary.loess"         
#>  [91] "summary.manova"         "summary.nls"            "summary.packageStatus" 
#>  [94] "summary.ppr"            "summary.prcomp"         "summary.princomp"      
#>  [97] "summary.table"          "summaryDefault"         "table"                 
#> [100] "tables_aov"             "ts"                     "tskernel"              
#> [103] "TukeyHSD"               "Type1Font"              "vignette"              
#> [106] "xtabs"
```

```r
all_class_definitions
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "princomp"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> cl[match("mlm", cl):length(cl)][-1L]
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "listof"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "pairwise.htest"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "Pair"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "dendrogram"
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> c("tables_aov", "list.of")
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> c("xtabs", "table")
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> c("summary.aov", "listof")
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] "nlsModel"
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[17]]
#> c("profiler.nls", "profiler")
#> 
#> [[18]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[19]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[20]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[21]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[22]]
#> c("stepfun", class(rval))
#> 
#> [[23]]
#> [1] "summary.aovlist"
#> 
#> [[24]]
#> [1] "loadings"
#> 
#> [[25]]
#> [1] "factanal"
#> 
#> [[26]]
#> [1] "ftable"
#> 
#> [[27]]
#> c("table", class(new.A))
#> 
#> [[28]]
#> if (any(other)) cl[other]
#> 
#> [[29]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[30]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[31]]
#> [1] "summary.nls"
#> 
#> [[32]]
#> c(if (maov) "maov", "aov", oldClass(er.fit))
#> 
#> [[33]]
#> attributes(x) <- NULL
#> 
#> [[34]]
#> [1] "summary.loess"
#> 
#> [[35]]
#> [1] "summaryDefault"
#> 
#> [[36]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[37]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[38]]
#> [1] "lm"
#> 
#> [[39]]
#> [1] "lm"
#> 
#> [[40]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[41]]
#> [1] "spec"
#> 
#> [[42]]
#> c("TukeyHSD", "multicomp")
#> 
#> [[43]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[44]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[45]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[46]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[47]]
#> [1] "loadings"
#> 
#> [[48]]
#> [1] "nls"
#> 
#> [[49]]
#> [1] "logLik"
#> 
#> [[50]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[51]]
#> [1] "ts"
#> 
#> [[52]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[53]]
#> [1] "formula"
#> 
#> [[54]]
#> [1] "summary.prcomp"
#> 
#> [[55]]
#> [1] "summary.glm"
#> 
#> [[56]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[57]]
#> [1] "aovproj"
#> 
#> [[58]]
#> c("aovprojlist", "listof")
#> 
#> [[59]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[60]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[61]]
#> [1] "formula"
#> 
#> [[62]]
#> c(oldClass(terms), "formula")
#> 
#> [[63]]
#> c("profile.nls", "profile")
#> 
#> [[64]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[65]]
#> if (nser > 1L) c("mts", "ts") else "ts"
#> 
#> [[66]]
#> [1] "loadings"
#> 
#> [[67]]
#> c("nlsModel.plinear", "nlsModel")
#> 
#> [[68]]
#> [1] "dendrogram"
#> 
#> [[69]]
#> [1] "table"
#> 
#> [[70]]
#> [1] "formula"
#> 
#> [[71]]
#> [1] "medpolish"
#> 
#> [[72]]
#> [1] "summary.lm"
#> 
#> [[73]]
#> [1] "summary.lm"
#> 
#> [[74]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[75]]
#> [1] "infl"
#> 
#> [[76]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[77]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[78]]
#> [1] "ar"
#> 
#> [[79]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[80]]
#> [1] "logLik"
#> 
#> [[81]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[82]]
#> [1] "listof"
#> 
#> [[83]]
#> [1] "prcomp"
#> 
#> [[84]]
#> [1] "spec"
#> 
#> [[85]]
#> [1] "summary.manova"
#> 
#> [[86]]
#> [1] "pairwise.htest"
#> 
#> [[87]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[88]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[89]]
#> c(if (mlm) "mlm", "lm")
#> 
#> [[90]]
#> [1] "summary.ppr"
#> 
#> [[91]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[92]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[93]]
#> [1] "hclust"
#> 
#> [[94]]
#> [1] "dist"
#> 
#> [[95]]
#> [1] "listof"
#> 
#> [[96]]
#> [1] "stl"
#> 
#> [[97]]
#> c("sortedXyData", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[98]]
#> [1] "ts"
#> 
#> [[99]]
#> [1] "arima0"
#> 
#> [[100]]
#> [1] "mtable"
#> 
#> [[101]]
#> c("tables_aov", "list.of")
#> 
#> [[102]]
#> c("manova", oldClass(result[[i]]))
#> 
#> [[103]]
#> c("manova", oldClass(result))
#> 
#> [[104]]
#> [1] "htest"
#> 
#> [[105]]
#> [1] "logLik"
#> 
#> [[106]]
#> [1] "tskernel"
#> 
#> [[107]]
#> [1] "integrate"
#> 
#> [[108]]
#> [1] "summary.princomp"
#> 
#> [[109]]
#> c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))
#> 
#> [[110]]
#> [1] "loadings"
#> 
#> [[111]]
#> [1] "logLik"
#> 
#> [[112]]
#> c("anova", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[113]]
#> [1] "pairwise.htest"
#> 
#> [[114]]
#> [1] "StructTS"
#> 
#> [[115]]
#> [1] "Date"
#> 
#> [[116]]
#> [1] "Date"
#> 
#> [[117]]
#> [1] "recordedplot"
#> 
#> [[118]]
#> [1] "Type1Font"
#> 
#> [[119]]
#> c("RGBcolorConverter", class(rval))
#> 
#> [[120]]
#> c(type, "Pattern")
#> 
#> [[121]]
#> [1] "raster"
#> 
#> [[122]]
#> [1] "colorConverter"
#> 
#> [[123]]
#> [1] "CairoSymbolFont"
#> 
#> [[124]]
#> [1] "CIDFont"
#> 
#> [[125]]
#> [1] "raster"
#> 
#> [[126]]
#> [1] "Latex"
#> 
#> [[127]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[128]]
#> [1] "packageStatus"
#> 
#> [[129]]
#> c("relistable", class(x))
#> 
#> [[130]]
#> [1] "Bibtex"
#> 
#> [[131]]
#> [1] "citationFooter"
#> 
#> [[132]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[133]]
#> [1] "vignette"
#> 
#> [[134]]
#> c("summary.packageStatus", "packageStatus")
#> 
#> [[135]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[136]]
#> [1] "packageDescription"
#> 
#> [[137]]
#> setdiff(class(x), "relistable")
#> 
#> [[138]]
#> [1] "hsearch"
#> 
#> [[139]]
#> [1] "browseVignettes"
#> 
#> [[140]]
#> [1] "person"
#> 
#> [[141]]
#> c("aspell", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[142]]
#> [1] "dump.frames"
#> 
#> [[143]]
#> [1] "bibentry"
#> 
#> [[144]]
#> [1] "hsearch_db"
#> 
#> [[145]]
#> c("aspell_inspect_context", "data.frame")
#> 
#> [[146]]
#> [1] "citationHeader"
#> 
#> [[147]]
#> [1] "sessionInfo"
#> 
#> [[148]]
#> [1] "packageIQR"
#> 
#> [[149]]
#> [1] "person"
#> 
#> [[150]]
#> [1] "socket"
#> 
#> [[151]]
#> [1] "packageIQR"
#> 
#> [[152]]
#> ClassDef@className
#> 
#> [[153]]
#> ClassDef@className
#> 
#> [[154]]
#> S3Class[[1L]]
#> 
#> [[155]]
#> unique.default(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))
#> 
#> [[156]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[157]]
#> c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
#> 
#> [[158]]
#> c("srcfilealias", "srcfile")
#> 
#> [[159]]
#> c(attr(obj, "class"), if (right) c(right = "noquote") else "noquote")
#> 
#> [[160]]
#> cl[-(1L:(i - 1L))]
#> 
#> [[161]]
#> c("srcfilecopy", "srcfile")
#> 
#> [[162]]
#> [1] "packageInfo"
#> 
#> [[163]]
#> [1] "libraryIQR"
#> 
#> [[164]]
#> [1] "table"
#> 
#> [[165]]
#> [1] "NativeRoutineMap"
#> 
#> [[166]]
#> [1] "qr"
#> 
#> [[167]]
#> c("ordered", "factor")
#> 
#> [[168]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[169]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[170]]
#> class(x)[-1]
#> 
#> [[171]]
#> [1] "factor"
#> 
#> [[172]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[173]]
#> [1] "DLLRegisteredRoutines"
#> 
#> [[174]]
#> class(x)[-1]
#> 
#> [[175]]
#> [1] "summary.table"
#> 
#> [[176]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[177]]
#> [1] "factor"
#> 
#> [[178]]
#> c("summaryDefault", "table")
#> 
#> [[179]]
#> [1] "srcfile"
#> 
#> [[180]]
#> [1] "table"
#> 
#> [[181]]
#> class(current) <- NULL
#> 
#> [[182]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[183]]
#> [1] "numeric_version"
#> 
#> [[184]]
#> c("srcfilealias", "srcfile")
#> 
#> [[185]]
#> c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>